# How to invert Meld comparison windows order with git difftool command?

Tags: git, meld

I recently start to use command `git difftool --dir-diff` as comparison tool with Meld as tool.

After runs this command on working tree folder opens a Meld's comparison window without problems but the window open with the HEAD on left and the working directory at the right.

I want invert the order of these windows. It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The `git difftool` creates temporary folders on `/tmp/git-difftool` as cache. One folder called *left* and other folder called *right*.

So just change the order on Meld dropdown compare menu and it is done.